# SMS tag wiki is ridiculously long

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-wiki, content

The description for the [sms](/questions/tagged/sms) tag seems to have been copied/pasted from a Wikipedia-like source, and is thus incredibly long (it goes into the history of SMS messaging, complete with dates).

One could argue it even breaks formatting a bit, as it causes undesirable overlap of some elements.

Would it be beneficial to give it a formal description better suited for its use as a tag on SO?

Comment: Well, it is, notice the "source" link at the end.  To answer your question, yes.  And it should probably be renamed "short-message-service" with "sms" being a synonym of that.

Comment: I edited the excerpt. Just need to be approved (because I am but a lowly pleb).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plagiarism on tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237839/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173807/282094